# Are $\{f>0 ~ \& ~ \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x^3} ~ \text{exists}\}$ and $\{\frac{\partial^3 \log f}{\partial x^3} ~ \text{exists}\}$ equivalent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, logarithms

> **Question.** Are the following conditions equivalent?
>   \begin{align}
> \textbf{Condition 1}: \quad &
> f > 0 ~ \text{and} ~ \frac{\partial^{3} f}{\partial x^{3}} ~ \text{exists}. \\
> \textbf{Condition 2}: \quad &
> \frac{\partial^{3} \log f}{\partial x^{3}} ~ \text{exists}.
> \end{align}

---

**My answer**:

Yes, first I show that Condition 2 implies Condition 1. Obviously, if $ f \leq 0 $, then $ \dfrac{\partial^{3} \log f}{\partial x^{3}} $ will not exist, therefore $ f > 0 $. Since $ f = e^{\log{f}} $, we can easily see that if $ \dfrac{\partial^{3} \log f}{\partial x^{3}} $ exists, then $ \dfrac{\partial^{3} f}{\partial x^{3}} $ exists.

Now, I show that Condition 1 implies Condition 2. By the chain rule of derivation ([Faà di Bruno’s Formula](http://www.sroman.com/matharticles/FaaDiBruno.pdf)), if all necessary derivatives are defined, then
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial^{3} \log f}{\partial x^{3}}
& = \frac{\partial^{3} \log f}{\partial f^{3}}
    \left( \frac{\partial^{3} f}{\partial x^{3}} \right)^3 +
    3 \frac{\partial^{2} \log f}{\partial f^{2}}
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}} +
    \frac{\partial \log f}{\partial f}
    \frac{\partial^{3} f}{\partial x^{3}} \\
& = \frac{2}{f^{3}}
    \left( \frac{\partial^{3} f}{\partial x^{3}} \right)^{3} +
    3 \frac{-1}{f^{2}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
    \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}} +
    \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial^{3} f}{\partial x^{3}}.
\end{align}
Thus, Condition 1 implies Condition 2.

---

Please let me know if I am correct and if both conditions above are indeed equivalent.

Comment: see modified function